# Как три модератора пришли к единому мнению

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, перевод-содержимого

На вопрос [C++ Set или List](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/101182/181472) дан [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/101200/181472) с большой цитатой из англоязычного ответа.

Один участник обратил внимание модераторов на то, что цитату хорошо бы перевести. Мы обсудили и пришли к единому мнению:

[image: Модераторское вече решило]

Автор в последнее время не посещает ru.SO, ему писать бесполезно. Мы по разным причинам не можем. (Например, я не знаю [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b))

Кто может перевести? Пожалуйста, отпишитесь в комментариях.

Comment: Никто не знает [tag:с++]. Есть только те, кто думают, что знают.

Comment: "Как три модератора пришли к единому мнению" - звучит как название басни

Comment: Насколько я полагаю, четыре согласия с ответом при отсутствии несогласных является признаком достаточного качества перевода. Внёс правку в ответ в том вопросе.

Comment: @Arhad спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Более-менее вольный перевод (отсебятина была необходима для более грамотного звучания на русском языке):

> ... в 90% случаев `std::vector` будет наилучшим выбором. Да, связный список выглядит привлекательнее в подавляющем большинстве случаев, поскольку порядок элементов для него (как правило) несущественен. Иными словами, добавляемые элементы помещаются в конец буфера-контейнера *[вне зависимости от места их вставки — прим. пер.]*, а удаляемый элемент предварительно обменивается местами с конечным, так что вставка и удаление затрагивают только элемент в конце этого буфера.
>
> Вектор, в свою очередь, копирует свои элементы при каждом расширении своего буфера, однако на практике это несущественно. Экспонециальный рост гарантирует, что среднее количество копирований стремится к некоторой константе, как правило трём или около того.
>
> Даже если копирование действительно является для вас проблемой (к примеру, элементы имеют большой размер), я всё равно не перешёл бы на связный список. Вместо этого я использовал бы `std::deque`. Это, по сути, вектор указателей на блоки с элементами. Он редко копирует что-либо при расширении, а если и копирует, то только эти указатели, но не сами элементы. Однако вектор является всё-же более предпочтительным выбором, пока вам не требуются возможности, присущие именно деку (вставка в любой из концов и удаление из них); но даже дек предпочтительнее, чем список. Иными словами, сначала `std::vector`, потом `std::deque` и только в самом конце `std::list`.

Не знаю, насколько этот перевод приемлем, так что публикую пока здесь, на Мете.